# Why don't I have "permission" to delete files off my USB bootable drive?

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files, files, usb, permissions

I'm the only admin/user on my laptop, so I don't know why this is an issue.

I right-clicked on the files, and under "permissions" it shows that I'm the owner and there are options that can be toggled.  I gave myself (cytosage) the ability to Read, Write, and Execute, but it didn't help.

[[image]][1

[image]

Comment: In the attached picture you only have Read and Execute permissions but not write permissions. Anyway, this issue may happen if you dualboot windows with this disk plugged in. Let me know if that's the case and I'll explain how to solve it.

Comment: I don't have windows on my PC or any other OS.  There are a number of times where I have to go through many loops to delete something, it wasn't that way w/windows and I miss that a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you do not have the permission to delete some files within that folder.  The permission applied to the folder itself does not automatically get replicated to all its children. You need to open a terminal and use the command line for that (use the command `man chmod` to see further information if you need to).  Alternatively you can try opening Files in administrator mode.  Right click on the dock Files icon (or in the Applications menu if it is not pinned in the dock) and choose "Open New Window as Administrator". You will need to enter your administrator password. You can then delete any file but will not be able to recover it if you make a mistake. In either case be careful to change/delete only files that can be safely removed. It is easy to break things in this mode.

Note that if you mess with a bootable drive you will not be able to boot from it again. If you want to turn it into an "ordinary" USB drive then it may be easier to reformat it using e.g. gparted.  Be sure you reformat the correct drive!